# Translate WMS version 1.3.0 to 1.1.1

Tags: wms, translation

I have a WMS version 1.3.0 which I want to use in a WebMapping application. The problem is that this application requires WMS version 1.1.1. Is there any way or tool to translate it from 1.3.0 to 1.1.1, like generate WMS version 1.1.1 from WMS 1.3.0 (maybe through GeoServer or FME) ?

Comment: you can define which version do you need to run, https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html

Comment: WMS request parameters. At least a LAYERS param is required. STYLES is '' by default. VERSION is 1.3.0 by default. WIDTH, HEIGHT, BBOX and CRS (SRS for WMS version < 1.3.0) will be set dynamicall, If you are using openalyers you set to your desirable verion https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileWMS-TileWMS.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GeoServer install will allow you to [cascade](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html) your remote 1.3.0 WMS to a local one which supports 1.1.1 and 1.3.0.